# What does "269681087" represent in FileSystemRights?

Tags: file

Like "65536" represent "Delete" in FileSystemRights. Then what does "269681087" represent in FileSystemRights?

Thank you!

Aleady read:
https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights?view=net-6.0

Comment: It should be the sum (or rather "bitwise OR") of a number of those enum values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value should be a combination of flags from that [FileSystemRights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights) enum.

For instance `FileSystemRights.ReadData | FileSystemRights.WriteData` allows both reading and writing of data. That `|` is the [bitwise OR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-or-operator-) operator.

Code to test for specific values:

```cs
var val = (System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights)269681087;

foreach(FileSystemRights fsr in Enum.GetValues(typeof(FileSystemRights)))
{
    if ((val & fsr) == fsr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{fsr} (0x{(int)fsr:X} = {(int)fsr})");
    }
}
```

This gives a list of values, with some apparent duplicates. The reason is that for instance AppendData and CreateDirectories share the same underlying value (4) so the ToString (implicit in that `{fsr}`) cannot distinguish between them and chooses the first matching text value.

> ReadData (0x1 = 1)
> ReadData (0x1 = 1) = ListDirectory
> CreateFiles (0x2 = 2)
> CreateFiles (0x2 = 2) = WriteData
> AppendData (0x4 = 4)
> AppendData (0x4 = 4) = CreateDirectories
> ReadExtendedAttributes (0x8 = 8)
> WriteExtendedAttributes (0x10 = 16)
> ExecuteFile (0x20 = 32)
> ExecuteFile (0x20 = 32) = Traverse
> ReadAttributes (0x80 = 128)
> WriteAttributes (0x100 = 256)
> Write (0x116 = 278)
> Delete (0x10000 = 65536)
> ReadPermissions (0x20000 = 131072)
> Read (0x20089 = 131209)
> ReadAndExecute (0x200A9 = 131241)
> Modify (0x301BF = 197055)
> Synchronize (0x100000 = 1048576)

But even then, when I combine all matching values I don't get your original value back: a value 0x1000_0000 is unaccounted for.